# Using an external editor (atom) with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Could someone provide step by step instructions on how to use Atom as the default editor with IntelliJ 2023 community edition. On one install I seem to remember it saying the vi editor was going to be used and gave me an option to select other editors.  I now can't find that option

Comment: JetBrains IDEs don't support using external editors. It sounds like you're remembering the official Vim plugin (IdeaVim), which tries to emulate the behavior of Vim but doesn't actually use an external Vim instance

Comment: Also, Atom was discontinued (official sunset on December 15, 2022: https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/). You might be interested in trying JetBrains Fleet: https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/